# is there free OS X equivalent to Total Commander?

Tags: software-recommendation, uti

is there **free** equivalent to Total Commander for OSX?

- two panels
- drag & drop
- tabs
- etc ect

I found DoubleCommander the best but OSX port has its bugs. muCommander is nice too but not as good as DoubleCommnader.

Comment: see also http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/10097/what-orthodox-file-manager-for-os-x-could-i-use

Answer (score 6):

I am satisfied with [Forklift](http://www.binarynights.com). Although it costs $20 after trial period, it is a simple yet powerful replacement of Finder/Total Commander.

What I value the most over other alternatives:

- **Simple and clear UI**: power is under the hood
- Easy switch between 1 or 2 panels (mostly I use only one)
- Option to setup shortcuts: Enter to open file, backspace to move up
- Regular Expression for filters
- Renaming multiple files
- Sync folder: showing added/deleted/modified files
- WebDav is much faster then in Finder

See http://www.binarynights.com for all features and screenshot.

Answer (score 5):

[TotalFinder](http://totalfinder.binaryage.com/) became a commercial solution not long ago: the full beta development stage was free and gave me plenty of time to test the software. It's an excellent solution, and I have seen almost every single bug disappear progressively.

Even if not a free solution anymore, its source is available on GitHub. I would recommend it on the grounds that it already works wonderfully well, and definitely deserve some support in my (otherwise freeware-oriented) opinion.

If freeware is yet a compulsory feature for you, Geekosaur's link has a few options.

Edit, 2013-01-07: as mentioned in another answer, [XtraFinder](http://www.trankynam.com/xtrafinder/) looks like TotalFinder, but free.

Answer (score 5):

Try [XtraFinder](http://www.trankynam.com/xtrafinder/). Is like TotalFinder, but it's free

Comment: Can you provide, some additional information (e.g. a link and a short description)?

Answer (score 2):

[Path Finder](http://www.cocoatech.com/) or [TotalFinder](http://totalfinder.binaryage.com/), perhaps?  (Both are commercial.)

Comment: I totally forgot to mentioned that it must be free/open source

Comment: http://alternativeto.net/software/double-commander/ lists some possibilities, but I suspect you've got the best you'll find.

Answer (score 1):

I'm writing an app similar to total commander, Mover - http://themaninhat.com/mover

Comment: It would be great if you could add some detail to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably take a look at Disk Order. It was created as a Total Commander equivalent for OS X. http://likemac.ru/english
However it's not free either...

Answer (score 0):

DCommander is a good alternative but it is not free.
See http://www.devstorm-apps.com/dcommander-mac/ or itunes directly: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/dcommander/id583622672?mt=12

Answer (score -1):

[FastCommander](http://osx-fastcommander.appspot.com) supports all file operations. Fast, stable, small, lightweight.

Can be freely downloaded and used - no restrictions, just nag screen.